# Annotating function argument accepting an instance of a class decorated with @define

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-attrs, type-annotation

I'm using pythons `attrs` package to `@define` some classes containing some members with little logic for isolation purposes.
However, when I run the following stripped down example:

```
from attrs import define

@define
class DefTest:
    attr1: int = 123
    attr2: int = 456
    attr3: str = "abcdef"


x = DefTest()
print(type(x))
```

it justs outputs `<class '__main__.DefTest'>`, with now hint which type it is derived from.
Even `type(x).mro()` outputs `[<class '__main__.DefTest'>, <class 'object'>]`, with no reference to some internally defined `attrs` class.

Now, imagine a function which takes an `attrs` class instance and performs some action on it. How can I add a proper type annotation, instead of the placeholder?

```py
from attrs import asdict, define
import json


def asjson(attrsclass: "DefineDecoratedClass"):
    return json.dumps(asdict(attrsclass))
```

I tried annotating using `attrs.AttrsInstance` which seems to be wrong from the linters perspective.
Any idea?

Comment: Why do you assume that `attrs` creates its own class and replaces the one you defined?

Comment: It was a reasonable assumption for me that `attrs` offers it's functionality in some baseclass.

Comment: Investigating the code of `attrs` a little bit, looks like (for your case) it just adds the functionality with `setattr` to the original class, e.g. [here](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/b950cb8d83789de9824f39808ddac64a06cc3031/src/attr/_make.py#L757)

Comment: This seems to answer my question as the 'setattr' does not introduce any type which I could use for type hinting. So, the answer would be that it is impossible to type hint a parameter accepting a class defined using `@attrs.define`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can. Simply put, "having applied a decorator on" is not a type-related thing.

Comment: I leave this open for s.b. to provide an answer if he wants to get some points. However, for me it's clear, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an *attrs* maintainer and I sometimes work on the attrs Mypy plugin.

*attrs* will not inject a class into your MRO; this is entirely by design to let you have complete control over your class tree. The way to recognize an attrs class is to look for the presence of an `__attrs_attrs__` class attribute, which is how the [`AttrsInstance`](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/b950cb8d83789de9824f39808ddac64a06cc3031/src/attr/_typing_compat.pyi#L8) protocol is defined in the first place.

Note that you need to use `type[AttrsInstance]` if you're looking for an *attrs* **class**, as opposed to an **instance** of an *attrs* class.

The Mypy plugin correctly generates the `__attrs_attrs__` marker, so this protocol should work with the latest version of Mypy. Pyright doesn't, and since [PEP 681 (dataclass transforms)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/) makes no provisions for this and Pyright has no plugin system, I believe there's nothing we can do about it.